# How can I copy debug symbols flags from one build configuration to another?

Tags: cmake

I created a new custom CMake build configuration called "Profile". I wish it to be based on the default flags of the "RelWithDebInfo". In other parts of my cmake I enable specific preprocessor definitions for this configuration.

This is how I set it:

```
set(ULTRA_ALLOWED_BUILD_TYPES Debug RelWithDebInfo Profile)

# Copy flags from RelWithDebInfo
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_PROFILE "Release") # see https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/discussions/19327 for why we need to do this

get_property(isMultiConfig GLOBAL
    PROPERTY GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG
)

# For multi-configuration generators, use generator expressions
if(isMultiConfig)
    set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES ${ULTRA_ALLOWED_BUILD_TYPES} CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

# add_compile_definitions($<CONFIG:Profile>:ULTRA_PROFILING_ENABLED)
else()
    set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "${ULTRA_ALLOWED_BUILD_TYPES}")

    if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE OR(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE IN_LIST ULTRA_ALLOWED_BUILD_TYPES))
        message(FATAL_ERROR
            "Missing or invalid build type: ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}\n"
            "Set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to one of : ${ULTRA_ALLOWED_BUILD_TYPES}"
        )
    endif()
endif()
```

This configuration works. however, the created project does not have debug symbols enabled (`/Zi` flag under MSVC)

So how can I copy the flags that enable debug symbols from the "RelWithDebInfo" configuration?

Comment: "In other parts of my cmake I enable specific preprocessor definitions for this configuration." Where exactly do you set these? They must be set in the top-level CMakeLists.txt after the first `project` call and before adding subdirectories to ensure that the value is the same in all subdirectories. I'd also like to point out that adding additional configurations usually is a bad idea. If you ever add 3rdparty libraries to be built alongside your project these libraries usually don't work well with unexpected build types. You can use a toolchain file with the required settings instead.

Comment: Do you happen to use CMake version 3.25 or later, with the `cmake_minimum_required` version also set to 3.25 or later? Because then the issue is that none of the `RELWITHDEBINFO` flags contain `/Zi`, as this is controlled by the value of `CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT` instead. The default value of that is `$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>`, which sets `/Zi` for the `Debug` and `RelWithDebInfo` configuration, but not your custom config. These kind of generator expressions are precisely what I meant when I wrote "usually don't work well" in the previous  comment.

Comment: @Corristo I do have a minimum requirements of CMake 3.25 (I use CMakePresets.json workflows). Could you please provide an example on how to set the CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a minimum required version of 3.25 and later CMake no longer adds the debug info flags to `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>` directly when compiling with MSVC. Therefore you can't copy them from the `RelWithDebInfo` configuration to your custom `Profile` configuration, because they're not part of the `RelWithDebInfo` flag variables in the first place.

That change was made to allow users to more easily change them (e.g. to use `/Z7` instead of `/Zi`), which previously required knowledge about which flags were set by CMake under which condition to then use `string(REPLACE)` to correctly replace them.

To control the type of debug info CMake now uses a target property called `MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT`, which is initialized to the value of `CMAKE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT`. This target property can be set to one of three values:

- `ProgramDatabase`: This will set `/Zi`
- `Embedded`: This will set `/Z7`
- `EditAndContinue`: This will set `/ZI`

If the user hasn't set a value, CMake will use `$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>` by default, i.e. use `/Zi` for the `Debug` and `RelWithDebInfo` configurations, and no debug info flags otherwise, including your custom configuration.

To fix this, you can add a

```
set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo,Profile>:ProgramDatabase>")
```

call in your top-level CMakeLists.txt before any targets are defined.

However, I'd strongly recommend not to add a custom configuration. The issue that a generator expression makes assumptions about the set of available configurations does not only affect CMake, but most libraries make use of similar generator expressions or otherwise implicitly depend on the set of configurations being fixed. If you ever add third-party libraries to be built from source as part of your project, either through `FetchContent`, a package-manager like `vcpkg`, or even by vendoring them in your repository, you're bound to run into these troubles. Even your own project currently has code to reject unknown configurations in single generator mode and thus wouldn't work well if someone else tried to include it in their own project with their custom configuration!

The better solution is to use a dedicated [CMake toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) that sets the required flags for your compiler, and to then add a preset that uses that toolchain file. This has the added benefit that  the toolchain file is reusable and you can build any CMake project with the same settings.